# UIViewController view not full screen XCode 6

Tags: ios7, uiviewcontroller, xcode6

I made a simple app using XCode 6 but something wrong is happening with its view frame.

The frame of the UIViewController's view is not covering full screen and moreover the status bar is also shifted by some distance.Can someone give me any clue?[image]

P.S I am testing it on iOS7 device

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just able to solve the question.

There was a launch image missing for 4 inch -device which was shown as warning in XCode , just clicking over the warning solved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Exactly, you have to add launch images for every size in order to display the apps correctly in every device